# how to use Laravel Pipeline?

Tags: php, laravel, pipeline

I have a `User` model, several external services are attached to it (`Services` model, multiple communication),
I don’t know in advance how many external integrations there will be, what settings they have (each service is implemented as a separate class, and the integration settings are described in the properties of the `Services` model).

I want to use the Pipeline template. But I can't find any good Laravel code examples and documentation.

It should look something like

```
$integrations = $user->integrations;
if ($integrations->count()) {
   return app(Pipeline::class)
      -> send($user)
      -> through($integrations)
      -> thenReturn();
}
```

But i cannot understand how it works inside... how to implement Pipes classes?

Answer (score 1):

Each pipe is essentially a class that handles a piece of logic. The class should define an handle method:

```
namespace App\Pipes;

class SomeServiceIntegration
{
    public function handle($user, \Closure $next)
    {
        // ur codes
        
        return $next($user);
    }
}
```

You can use the Pipeline class to send an object through the defined pipes:

```
use Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline;

$integrations = $user->integrations;

if ($integrations->count()) {
    // at here., you need to get the classes (pipes) for each integration
    $pipes = $integrations->map(function ($integration) {
        return $integration->serviceClass; // i assume that you store the full class path in the 'serviceClass' attribute
    })->toArray();

    return app(Pipeline::class)
        ->send($user)
        ->through($pipes)
        ->thenReturn();
}
```

If each service has its own settings, you may need to add  settings:

```
$pipes = $integrations->map(function ($integration) {
    return app($integration->serviceClass, ['settings' => $integration->settings]);
})->toArray();
```

And adjust the SomeServiceIntegration class to accept settings:

```
namespace App\Pipes;

class SomeServiceIntegration
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __construct($settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function handle($user, \Closure $next)
    {
        // u can use $this->settings here easily :○

        return $next($user);
    }
}
```